# Simple csv comma delimited html table gen

Tags: c#, csv, html-table

I know the question has been asked before, but I wasn't quite satisfied with the answer (considering it didn't explain what was going on).

My specific question is :How do I open a csv/text file that's comma delimited and rows are separated by returns and put it into an HTML table using C#?

I understand how to do this in PHP but I have just started learning ASP.Net/C#, if anyone has some free resources for C# and/or is able to provide me with a snippet of code with some explanation of whats going on I would appreciate it.

I have this code, but I'm not sure how I would use it because A)I don't know how C# arrays work and B)I'm not sure how to open files in ASP.Net C#:

```
var lines =File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
    using (var outfs = File.AppendText(args[1]))
    {
        outfs.Write("<html><body><table>");
        foreach (var line in lines)
            outfs.Write("<tr><td>" + string.Join("</td><td>", line.Split(',')) + "</td></tr>");
        outfs.Write("</table></body></html>");
    }
```

I apologize for my glaring inexperience here.

Comment: Arrays: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Reading text files: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I have updated my original question to answer your question: My specific question is :How do I open a csv/text file that's comma delimited and rows are separated by returns and put it into an HTML table using C#?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're asking - the code you posted will do exactly what you want - open a CSV file, write out an HTML table based on the data in the input file.  It seems like what you're really asking is "How does this work?"

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Tim. What part of the code that you posted are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sample you posted does exactly what you're asking:

1. Opens a file.
2. Writes a string of HTML for a table with the contents of the file from step 1 to another file.

Let's break it down:

```
var lines =File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
```

This opens the file specified in args[0] and reads all the lines into a string array, one lay per element.  See [File.ReadAllLines Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

```
using (var outfs = File.AppendText(args[1])) 
{
```

[File.AppendText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) creates a StreamWriter to append text to an existing file (or creates it if it doesn't exist).  The filename (and path, possibly) are in args[1].   The `using` statement puts the StreamWriter into what is called a using block, to ensure the stream is correctly disposed once the using block is left.  See [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for more information.

```
    outfs.Write("<html><body><table>");
```

`outfs.Write` calls the Write method of the StreamWriter ([StreamWriter.Write Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx)).  Actually in the case of your code snippet nothing is written to the file until you exit the using block - it's written to a buffer.  Exiting the using block will flush the buffer and write to the file.

```
    foreach (var line in lines)
```

This command starts a loop through all the elements in the string array `lines`, staring with the first (element 0) index.  See [foreach, in (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information if you need it.

```
        outfs.Write("<tr><td>" + string.Join("</td><td>", line.Split(',')) + "</td></tr>");
```

String.Join is the key part here, where most of the work is done.  [String.Join Method (String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) has the technical details, but essentially what is happening here is that the second argument (`line.Split(',')`) is passing in an array of strings, and the strings in that array are then being concatenated together with the first argument (`</td><td>`) as the separator, and the table row is being opened and closed.

For example, if the line is "1,2,3,4,5,6", the `Split` gives you a 6 element array.  This array is then conatenated with `</td><td>` as the separator by `String.Join`, so you have `"1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6"`.  `"<tr><td>"` is added to the front and `"</td></tr>"` is added to the end and the final line is `"<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>"`.

```
    outfs.Write("</table></body></html>");     
}
```

This writes the end of the HTML to the buffer, which is then flushed and written to the specified text file.

A couple of things to note.  `args[0]` and `args[1]` are used to hold command line arguments (i.e., MakeMyTable.exe InFile.txt OutFile.txt), which aren't (in my experience) applicable to ASP.NET applications.  You'll need to either code the files (and paths) necessary, or allow the user to specify the input file and/or output file.  The ASP.NET application will need to be running under an account that has permission to access those files as well.

If you have quoted values in the CSV file, you'll need to handle those (this is very common when dealing with monetary amounts, for example), as splitting on the `,` may cause an incorrect split.  I recommend taking a look at [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx), as it can handle quoted fields quite easily.

Unless you're sure that each line in the file has the same number of fields, you run the risk of having poorly formed HTML in your table and no guarantees on how it will render.

Additionally, it would be advisable to test that the file you're opening exists.  There's probably more, but these are the basics (and may already be beyond the scope of Stack Overflow).

Comment: I didn't mean to sound so daft in my original post but I did kind of see what was going on with the open file line `var lines =File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);` but was confused by the array being there and no designation of an actual file location within the code. Also, I have no use for handling quotes, there will never be quotes in my csv file, I apologize for not making that clear. And to end, thank you for trying to clear up things for me, it seems my whole issue with not understanding this stems from the `args[0]` array.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help point you in the right direction:

```
line = "<table>" + line;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    line = "<tr><td>" + line;
    line.Replace(",", "</td><td>");
    line += "</td></tr>";
}
Response.Write(line + "</table>");
```

Good luck with your learning!

Comment: You're missing an opening `<td>`.

Comment: In addition to the missing opening `<td>`, you're doing a lot of string concatentation, which can get expensive.  It'd be better to use StringBuilder.

Comment: @BeemerGuy.net True, sorry. The doorbell was ringing as I wrote this up so I was rushing. Fixed it now. Tim: Again, true, a StringBuilder would have been a better option. I was just trying to point OP in the right direction - hopefully they understand this method more than the one he/she posted.

Comment: @Event_Horizon So `String + String` actually generates a new String in memory, as Strings can't be modified. StringBuilder gets around that. You'd use, for example, `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line); sb.Insert(0, "<tr><td>"); sb.Append("</td></tr>");` to modify the line instead of the way I've shown above. See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.71).aspx